# Develop Search Control that can accept multiple search texts in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on a project that requires to search records by multiple customers, I an easily do that by making CheckList box but that will look pity, I've one example which I am trying to create in WPF, upto this point I am only able to do that to auto populate matching values but I want it to be like following.

[image: Example]

If There is any control which can help me to achieve this like Searching for Customer A and Customer B in the manner shown in Screen shot.

Comment: One such example using *DevExpress* control at https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-create-a-tokenbox-control-in-wpf-e5187

Comment: thanks i will go through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a composite control. You can develop it by creating an UserControl (preferred) or writing a CustomControl on WPF.

It's depends on your time limitations. Finding an Open-source solution is a fast and easy way. but it must fill your expectations.

Most important part of developing such a Control is to decompose the complex control in some known controls.

I see a WrapPanel as a Container for this control and a main TextBox (with AutoCompletion) into it. and there are some Button which are created by an event. 
for example you pressed the `Space Button` and the user control determined that **It is time to add a Button as a Item** into the main container (WrapPanel) and .... .